# Android: Restarting my App inserts a Database Entry

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I insert a Value into my Database at midnight once a day. However, when i restart my App, it inserts another entry. I cant find my mistake:

This is the part of the onReceive method, which calls the method that makes the entry:

```
if (mTaskList != null && mTaskList.size() > 0) {
                DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String date = df.format(c.getTime());
                String millisIdentifier;
                int doneState;

                for (int i = 0; i < mTaskList.size(); i++) {
                    millisIdentifier = mTaskList.get(i).getMilliIdentifier();
                    doneState = mTaskList.get(i).getDoneTodayValue();

                    mDbHelper.addDayCheck(millisIdentifier, date, doneState);

                    mTaskList.get(i).shiftDayChecks();
                    mTaskList.get(i).resetTimeLeft();
                }
            }
```

This is the method that actually makes the entry:

```
public void addDayCheck(String millisIdentifier, String date, int doneState){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    values.put(COLUMN_DONE_STATE, doneState);

    db.insert(millisIdentifier, null, values);
}
```

The onReceive method gets called at the correct time, i am sure of that. 
So i dont understand why it makes that entry at the start of the app.

Comment: The addDayCheck method is always called in the onReceive method which implies a new entry.

Comment: Right, but the onReceive method as a whole is only called once per day.

Comment: Could you paste the code that fires the broadcast?

Comment: I didnt add that, because all the rest of the onReceive method gets executed at the correct time. I can see that in what the app shows me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addDayCheck(String millisIdentifier, String date, int doneState) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        //read database and return a cursor 
        Cursor cursor;
        //............
        //.............
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String olddate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE));
                if (olddate.equals(date))
                    return;
                //You don't have to check if it's midnight again since there's no input matching today
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
        values.put(COLUMN_DONE_STATE, doneState);

        db.insert(millisIdentifier, null, values);
    }
```

I would have done it this way, by checking if today's entry has already been added, you can improve this by checking if it's midnight and in which case you proceed to adding a new entry.